# helm-mini doesn't show .org files in recentf

Tags: org-mode, helm, recentf

`helm-mini` has suddenly (since 2 days) stopped showing all `.org` files under the `recentf` category. However, my `recentf` file correctly records all the `.org` files that I have opened. I do not have this problem with files with other extensions saved in `recentf`, and `helm-mini` shows them all under `recentf`. I am using the latest (non-stable) version of `helm` from MELPA.  I am flummoxed and will appreciate any help.

My `recentf` config:

```
(require 'recentf)  
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 100)
```

My helm config:

```
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
(helm-autoresize-mode t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x) 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") 'helm-show-kill-ring)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'helm-mini)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c SPC") 'helm-all-mark-rings)
```

Comment: This just started happening for me as well. I noticed now this morning, but it may have been happening for a few days, I don't know. Really curious about the answer.

Comment: See: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1947

Comment: Thanks. The bug has been fixed and the problem is solved with the update.